# Schedule multiple cron jobs in same time in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have two different **cron jobs** below.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('eventnotification:mail');
    $schedule->command('workflownotification:mail');
}
```

How can I run both cron jobs by daily **6:00AM**?

Answer (score 1):

You can run schedules daily at a certain time using the `dailyAt()` function:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('eventnotification:mail')->dailyAt('6:00');
    $schedule->command('workflownotification:mail')->dailyAt('6:00');
}
```